# Definition of an irreducible subgroup, and how to tell if any subgroup of $\mathrm{GL}_{n}(p)$ is irreducible

Tags: rt.representation-theory, linear-algebra, finite-groups

I'm not entirely sure what the proper definition of an "irreducible subgroup". I want an intuitive definition  what an irreducible subgroup is in the simplest, most pedagogical terms as reasonably possible.

As a secondary question, I also want to know how to tell if any given subgroup of $\mathrm{GL}_{n}(p)$ (the complete group of linear automorphisms of an $n$-dimensional vector space over a finite Galois field of prime order $p$) is irreducible.

I don't know how to read any of the academic papers on the subject. They either have a payment lock, or have confusing notation that look like a foreign language to an average ungraduate student.

Comment: Regarding the issue of paywalls: many university libraries have subscriptions to a lot of papers and books, that faculty and students can access by logging into the library website. Check with your department if they may have that.

Comment: In the same spirit as @R.vanDobbendeBruyn, most more recent papers can be found on the https://arxiv.org/

Answer (score 5):

The notion exists both for (ordinary) groups and for *algebraic* groups, which are groups that are simultaneously algebraic varieties in a compatible way. Over fields that are not algebraically closed, the modern way to deal with these uses scheme-theory, which is probably beyond undergraduate mathematics. So let me focus on subgroups of the abstract group $\operatorname{GL}_n(k)$ instead of the algebraic group $\operatorname{GL}_{n,k}$.

**Definition.** Let $k$ be a field, and $G \subseteq \operatorname{GL}_n(k)$ a subgroup. Then $G$ is *irreducible* if the representation $G \to \operatorname{GL}_n(k)$ is irreducible. In other words, there is no subspace $V \subseteq k^n$ such that $g V \subseteq V$ for all $g \in G$, except $V = 0$ or $V = k^n$.

The other definition you often find is in terms of parabolic subgroups:

**Definition.** A subgroup $P \subseteq \operatorname{GL}_n(k)$ is *parabolic* if there is a flag $0 = V_0 \subsetneq \ldots \subsetneq V_r = k^n$ of subspaces for which $P$ is the stabiliser, i.e. $gV_i = V_i$ for all $i$ if and only if $g \in P$.

Then these notions are closely related:

**Lemma.** *Let $G \subseteq \operatorname{GL}_n(k)$ be a subgroup. Then $G$ is irreducible if and only if the only parabolic subgroup $P \subseteq \operatorname{GL}_n(k)$ containing $G$ is $P = \operatorname{GL}_n(k)$.*

*Proof.* If $G \subseteq P$ for a parabolic subgroup $P \subsetneq \operatorname{GL}_n(k)$ that is the stabiliser of some flag $0 = V_0 \subsetneq \ldots \subsetneq V_r = k^n$, then we must have $r \geq 2$ as $P \neq \operatorname{GL}_n(k)$. Then $V_1$ is a nontrivial $G$-subrepresentation of $k^n$, hence $G$ is not irreducible.

Conversely, if $G$ is not irreducible, there exists some subspace $V \subseteq k^n$ different from $0$ and $k^n$ such that $gV = V$ for all $g \in G$. Then the stabiliser of the flag $0 \subsetneq V \subsetneq k^n$ is a parabolic subgroup $P \subsetneq \operatorname{GL}_n(k)$ containing $G$. $\square$

**Example.** For concreteness' sake, you should probably compute some stabilisers. For example, the stabiliser in $\operatorname{GL}_2(k)$ of $V = \operatorname{span} {1 \choose 0} \subseteq k^2$ is the group of upper triangular matrices. In general, parabolic groups are conjugate to the block upper triangular form:
$$\left(\begin{array}{c|c|c} * & * & * \\\hline 0 & * & * \\\hline 0 & 0 & *\end{array}\right),$$
where the blocks on the diagonal are square (but not necessarily the others). Hint: choose a basis $v_1,\ldots,v_n$ of $k^n$ such that $V_i = \operatorname{span}(v_1,\ldots, v_{d_i})$ for $d_i = \dim V_i$.

**Remark.** As for deciding irreducibility, you have to do some work. Usually you show that a representation $V$ is irreducible by checking that for *any* nonzero vector $v \in V$, the conjugates $\{gv\ |\ g \in G\}$ span $V$. For example, the permutation matrices $S_n \subseteq \operatorname{GL}_n(k)$ are never irreducible, as $V = \operatorname{span}\Big(\begin{smallmatrix}1 \\ \vdots \\ 1\end{smallmatrix}\Big)$ is fixed by $S_n$. But $\{(x_1,\ldots,x_n)\ |\ \sum x_i = 0\} \subseteq k^n$ is irreducible as $S_n$-representation, at least when $n$ is invertible in $k$ (i.e. $\operatorname{char} k = 0$ or $\operatorname{char} k = p > 0$ and $p \nmid n$). (Exercise!)

Comment: The word "usual" in the first sentence is a bit loaded. I think the definition you give for subgroups of $\mathrm{GL}_n(k)$ is bog-standard.

Comment: @SeanEberhard I should have known that Serre himself (who seems to have coined the term) would be interested in finite groups, not algebraic groups.

Comment: It may be worth remarking that 'irreducible' in the context of algebraic groups *qua* schemes has an entirely different meaning.

Comment: @LSpice although I've never seen it used like that, as for groups this is equivalent to connected.

Comment: The conflation is a reasonable one. Analogous language is used for transitive actions / transitive subgroups of $S_n$.

Comment: @SeanEberhard, I'm not sure to which conflation you [refer](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/410152/definition-of-an-irreducible-subgroup-and-how-to-tell-if-any-subgroup-of-math/410158#comment1052561_410158).  One may certainly sensibly conflate the meanings of irreducible representation and irreducible subgroup, which is analogous to the case you mention, but not the meanings of irreducible subgroup and irreducible scheme.  Nonetheless, as @‍R.vanDobbendeBruyn points out, there really is no confusion likely, and I mentioned it just for completeness.

Comment: @LSpice I meant between representation and subgroup. Sorry, two conversations at once